# CAN Problems with MCP2515, MCP2561 and Rpi

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi, can, bus

I work with some devices which used STM32 MCU and MCP2561.
Theses devices talks on a CAN Bus.
Everything is ok.

But when i plug a Raspberry Pi with a MCP2515(Spi) and a MCP2561.
I see a lot of invalid frames on my scope like this :

[image]

A valid CAN Frame is like : 
[image]

A zoom on the problem : 
[image]

I don't understand why there is a problem at the ACK/ACK Delimiter.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: In your 'valid' frame, the `ACK` slot does not look right either. Why is it only at 2V? I assume you measure not only one line (CANH) but the difference between CANH and CANL, correct? What else is connected to the bus besides the scope? Do you have termination resistor(s) in place?

Comment: Looks like the RPI issues an error flag at the end. What do the status registers of the can controller read?

Comment: None of these are valid CAN frames, what exactly about them looks valid to you? Notably, there is no binary pulse train of data, did you think it was PWM-driven or something? These are repeated error frames at best. You have some fundamental hardware problem. See this: https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276251

Comment: It's a while ago, but this is probably caused by too low voltage rail. CAN tranceivers require 5V. USB is often lower than 5V, especially when loaded by an RPI.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Per ISO 11898 the dominant bits require only 1.5V differential, so there is absolutely no need for transceivers to require 5V. In fact, 3.3V CAN transceivers are quite common nowadays and they are interoperable with old 5V devices.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an electrical issue with one of the CAN signal leads or the grounds.  Check the continuity of those.

Next, make sure that the RPi is running some known-good code that initializes the CAN adapter properly. The adapter has to do a lot of work for the CAN protocol. It works semi-autonomously, so if it’s not set up properly it’ll reject frames.